# Common function in razor view to generate drop down in multiple view pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I have page which contains multiple dropdowns with option like

```
<option>1<option>
<option>2<option>
<option>3<option>
```

and

```
<option>-5<option>
<option>-6<option>
<option>-7<option>
```

so i have created in a function to generate dropdown options in razor view.

```
 @functions {
        public List<SelectListItem> GenerateDropDown(int startvalue, int endValue)
        {
            var dropDownList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            for (int i = startvalue; i <= endValue; i++)
            {
                string val = i.ToString();
                dropDownList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = val, Value = val });
            }
            return dropDownList;
        }
}
```

and using like this

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.xyz, GenerateDropDown(1, 10))
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Abc, GenerateDropDown(2, 20))
```

this work fine but i want use the same function in multiple pages with out code duplication i tried using helper method but no use can any one suggest me how to centralize GenerateDropDown function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Static Class, with static method GenerateDropDown in it.

Let's say

```
       public static class GeneratorHelper{

         public static List<SelectListItem> GenerateDropDown(int startvalue, int endValue)
            {
                var dropDownList = new List<SelectListItem>();
                for (int i = startvalue; i <= endValue; i++)
                {
                    string val = i.ToString();
                    dropDownList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = val, Value = val });
                }
                return dropDownList;
            }
       }
```

and now in the razor you just use the class as:

```
GeneratorHelper.GenerateDropDown(1,5);
```

Comment: @Achillius Thanks i crated Helper class and not made class as static,changed it now it works fine